# RegEx to extract parameters from url hash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, hash

My urls will look like:

```
http://example.com/whatever#page?x=1&locale=hu&y=2
http://example.com/whatever#page?x=1&locale=hu
http://example.com/whatever#page?locale=hu
http://example.com/whatever#page?locale=
http://example.com/whatever#page?x=1
http://example.com/whatever#page
http://example.com/whatever
```

I'd like to get the locale parameter or empty string if it's not set.

I'm trying something like:

```
locale = location.hash.replace(/.*(?:[?&]locale=([^&]*))?.*/, "$2");
```

But my problem is that I couldn't find the right RegExp that works for all cases (both when there's locale= in the hash and when there isn't)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that will extract it from the hash and avoid it anywhere else in the URL:

```
function getLocaleFromHash(url) {
    var match = url.match(/#.*[?&]locale=([^&]+)(&|$)/);
    return(match ? match[1] : "");
}
```

And, you can see it work on all your test cases here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/p37Mx/

---

If you want to be able to look for any parm in the hash, you would use this:

```
function getParmFromHash(url, parm) {
    var re = new RegExp("#.*[?&]" + parm + "=([^&]+)(&|$)");
    var match = url.match(re);
    return(match ? match[1] : "");
}
```

See it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6kgUk/

---

A more generic function that will fetch all parameters in the URL would look like this.  For normal URLs where the hash is after the query and the parameters are in the query string, it would look like this.  This is a bit more code because it does more.  It fetches all the parameters into an object where you can look up any parameter by it's key and it URL decodes them all too:

```
function getParmsFromURL(url) {
    var parms = {}, pieces, parts, i;
    var hash = url.lastIndexOf("#");
    if (hash !== -1) {
        // remove hash value
        url = url.slice(0, hash);
    }
    var question = url.lastIndexOf("?");
    if (question !== -1) {
        url = url.slice(question + 1);
        pieces = url.split("&");
        for (i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            parts = pieces[i].split("=");
            if (parts.length < 2) {
                parts.push("");
            }
            parms[decodeURIComponent(parts[0])] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
        }
    }
    return parms;
}
```

For a special version that handles parameters in a hash value and after a ? in the hash value like in the OP's question (which isn't the typical case), one could use this:

```
function getParmsFromURLHash(url) {
    var parms = {}, pieces, parts, i;
    var hash = url.lastIndexOf("#");
    if (hash !== -1) {
        // isolate just the hash value
        url = url.slice(hash + 1);
    }
    var question = url.indexOf("?");
    if (question !== -1) {
        url = url.slice(question + 1);
        pieces = url.split("&");
        for (i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            parts = pieces[i].split("=");
            if (parts.length < 2) {
                parts.push("");
            }
            parms[decodeURIComponent(parts[0])] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
        }
    }
    return parms;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/v8cd5/

And, then if you wanted the local option, you'd just do this:

```
var parms = getParmsFromURL(url);
var locale = parms["locale"];
```

Comment: I like this one, because it's easily reusable by passing the parameter I'm looking for to the function :)

Comment: @Gavriel - I added a more generic function that lets you pass in not only the URL, but also the parameter you're looking for in it.

Comment: thanks, I've already done it alone :) Just came back to post it, but it's identical to your 2nd function.

Comment: It would be better if you have written a function that takes Seperator,url,param as parameter

Comment: @RezaRahmati - I''m not sure what you mean.  The second version of the code lets you specify the parameter you're interested in.  I've also added a reference to a more powerful URL parsing object that does a lot more.

Comment: @jfriend00 When you try to get `y` parameter from this link `http://example.com/whatever?x=1&locale=hu&y=2` it will return empty string. (when there is no #sign in link) so I think it would be more general if you get '#' as parameter

Comment: @RezaRahmati - OK, I see your point.  This particular answer was geared only to parsing parameters out of the hash value.  Yes, it could be more general purpose for regular query parameters too.

Comment: @jfriend00 for that url I changed the `RegExp("#.*[?&]" + parm + "=([^&]+)(&|$)");` to `RegExp(".*[?&]" + parm + "=([^&]+)(&|$)");` it works but I don't know if it is correct or not. can you confirm?

Comment: @RezaRahmati - I added two versions of more generic code that parse all the parameters either out of a normal query string or out of a hash query.

Answer (score 2):

```
locale = location.hash.match( /[?&]locale=([^&]*)?/ );
locale = ( locale == null ? "" : locale[1] || "" );
```

Will do the trick. I don't think the `.*` are needed, because you do not specify a start or an end of the string.
I tested this regular expression on all your examples and they all worked correctly :)

**Edit:** sorry, it was invalid in some cases. It is now correct in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it in one regex:

```
locale = location.hash.match(/([?&]locale=|^((?![?&]locale=).)+$)([^&]*)/)[3];
```

It works against all of your examples, though I imagine it's horribly inefficient.